# Execute Animation DataTrigger with binding to Command

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm-light

I tried to execute animation with DataTrigger but it don't reise up.
Program don't throw any exception and errors.
Can someone explain why animation don't Start ?

Here is my storyboard

```
 <Storyboard x:Key="storyboard2" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="00:01:00">

        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.Target="{Binding Source={x:Reference RectangleScaleFrom}}" To="4" From="1"/>           
        <DoubleAnimation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.Target="{Binding Source={x:Reference RectangleScaleFrom}}"
                           From="4" To="1"/>
    </Storyboard>"
```

Here Is DataTrigger to start and Stop Animation

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RunAnimation}" Value="True" x:Key="Start">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="BeginScaleFrom" Storyboard="{StaticResource storyboard2}"/>
            <!--<BeginStoryboard x:Name="BeginScaleTo" Storyboard="{StaticResource storyboard2}"/>-->
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RunAnimation}" Value="False" x:Key="Stop">
        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BeginScaleFrom"/>
            <!--<StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BeginScaleTo"/>-->
        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
    </DataTrigger>
```

Here is Button

```
  <ToggleButton Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="50,20,50,30" FontSize="20" x:Name="StartButton" Style="{StaticResource StartStopButtonStyle}" Width="100" Height="50" Command="{Binding StartAnimation}">
    </ToggleButton>
```

And Command to start

```
  private bool _StartAnim = false;
    public bool RunAnimation
    {
        get => _StartAnim;
        set
        {
            _StartAnim = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(RunAnimation));
        }
    }
    public RelayCommand StartAnimation { get; private set; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        StartAnimation = new RelayCommand(() => RunAnimation = !RunAnimation);

    }
```

Comment: Can we assume that you checked the Output Window in Visual Studion for potential data binding error messages, and that you've set a breakpoint in the RunAnimation setter to make sure that it is executed?

Comment: @Clemens I set a breakpoint and it's executed becouse _StartAnim get value True

Comment: I notice your duration is a minute "00:01:00"  which will be pretty slow. Maybe you want something like second instead "0:0:1"

Comment: Also make sure you've actually set a ScaleTransform to the Rectangle's RenderTransform.

Comment: @Clemens ScaleTransform is set in Rectangle but it still don't work

Comment: Just another note, when you are using a ToggleButton you don't actually need the Command binding. You could as well bind the IsChecked property directly to RunAnimation.

Comment: @Clemens Yea I know but in my project i must use this solution becouse I set Animation parameters from textbox

Comment: `x:Key="Start"` in the DataTrigger implies that you have declared it as resource. That won't work. You have to add it to the Triggers collection of a Style or ControlTemplate.

Comment: @Clemens I tried do this way but if i place DataTrigger in my ControlTemplate, Program throw exception "Cannot Frozen TimeLine tree in  Storyboard for use across threads"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="storyboard2">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
            To="4" From="1" AutoReverse="True"
            RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="00:00:10"/>
        <DoubleAnimation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
            From="4" To="1" AutoReverse="True"
            RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="00:00:10"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RunAnimation}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="BeginScaleFrom"
                            Storyboard="{StaticResource storyboard2}"/>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BeginScaleFrom"/>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```